# JS: issues retreiving data from dynamic table on click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am building a light weight web application for use by the admissions team at a healthcare company.  Customer (patient) prospects are filling out forms on our website, and my app is intended to allow admissions staff to see a list of those forms, and assign each patient submission to a member of the admissions team. So I've put a select element (containing each admissions team member) in every row of the search results.   So the user can see a row of data for the patient and then choose a team member from the select dropdown.  I also added select element so admissions can track status of the patient (have they been contacted, do they require follow-up...etc).  Patient form submissions are rendered as search results according to the following HTML template.

```
<template id="rowtemplate">
      <tr scope="row">
       <th class="col1" id="patient">1</th><!--PROBLEM - NO IDs in Template...-->
       <th class="col2">1</th>
       <th class="col3">1</th>
       <th class="col4">1</th>
       <th class="col5"><select class="form-select staff" id="staffDD"> <!--PROBLEM - NO IDs in Template...-->
          <option>Assign To</option>
          <option>Kristen</option>
          <option>Heather</option>
          <option>Tammy</option>
          </select> </th>
      <th class="col6"><select class="form-select status" id="newStatus">
        <option selected>New Status</option>
        <option value="Needs Contact">Needs Contact</option>
        <option value="Needs Follow-up">Needs Follow-up</option>
        <option value="Contacted">Contacted</option>
        <option value="Not Interested">Not Interested</option>
        <option value = "Enrolled">Enrolled</option>
        <option value="Alumni">Alumni</option>
        </select> </th>
      <th class="col7"><button class="btn-primary-light add" id="detailbutton">DETAILS</button></th>
        </tr>
      </template>
```

So the question is, is it possible to grab the item selected from the drop down and then pass to server side?  Obviously , if you get the select choice and the patient name or ID you can send it to the server and append it the patient data.  But I am having much difficulty grabbing the data chosen in the staff assignment select.  I'm thinking I May need a submit choices button on each row so that I can append the data selected as a data attribute on that button.  Then I could use JS to obtain the patient name and staff select from the click event on the submit button...  Is there another way to get the information from the search result row without the submit button?

[This image does not include the first column of data which is the patient's name because it has actual names in it - but it is there.   I just want to make the selected data in the dropdowns available to grab with JS...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6gOQ.png)

Thanks for any advice on technique here....

Comment: Why not use a traditional back-end code for this as a form post passed to a php page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you means by `PROBLEM - NO IDs in Template`.

But I think you can solve this easily by modifying your HTML a bit.
There is no need to use id here, `<select><option>` only needs value to make it work. and To reference the element, you can use class attribute, instead of ID, if it is not present.

Here is the code:

```html
<th class="col5"><select class="form-select staff" id="staffDD">
          <option value="">Assign To</option>
          <option value="Kristen">Kristen</option>
          <option value="Heather">Heather</option>
          <option value="Tammy">Tammy</option>
</select> 
</th>
```

In this way, you can listen to the value selected, by using

```js
document.querySelector(".staff").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
     const value = event.target.value; 
     // code handling
});
```

or if you prefer to handle it only on submit

```js
const value = document.querySelector(".staff").value;
// code handling
```

Comment: Thank you, @CHANist.  Turned out the only issue was retrieving the select result using event.target.value.  But your simple response highlighted the obvious.  That comment you asked about was just a note telling myself that IDs are useless in a template.